# Minimize surface area by differentiation. What if maximization is required?

Tags: calculus

Given a cylinder has volume  $V = 1 \text{dm}^3.$

Calculate a solution so that surface area is minimal. Assume that the cyclinder has no lid , but only a bottom.

I calculated

$$ V = r^2\pi*h = 1 => \frac{1}{\pi*r^2} = h$$

$$ O = 2r\pi*h + r^2\pi$$

$$ O = 2r\pi*\frac{1}{\pi*r^2}  + r^2\pi$$

First Derivative of O: $$-\frac{2}{r^2} + 2r\pi = 0 => r = (\frac{1}{\pi})^{1/3} $$

Now with the second derivative I see that $$r = (\frac{1}{\pi})^{1/3}$$ is indeed a minimum. But since there is only one solution can I conclude that there is no maximum? For example If I wanted to maximize surface area, how could I do that with calculus?

Comment: Take $r=\frac 1 n, h=\frac {n^{2}} {\pi}$

Comment: You forgot a minus sign:$$V'=-\frac{2}{r^2}+2\pi r$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Corrected it: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm sorry I can't follow, what is n?

Comment: I am showng that we can keep the volume fixed at $1$ and make the surface area tend to $\infty$. So there is no maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Second derivative

$$ \frac{4}{r^3}+ 2 \pi= 4 \pi+2 \pi=6 \pi >0$$

So the surface area is a *minimum* and  that means for all other radii it has value *more* than this. The maximum is everywhere for other radii.

Surface area O is plotted  against radius $r$. It has a minimum at the value you found.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no maximum surface area: the first term is $2/r$, so you can make the surface area as large as you like by making $r$ small enough.